# SQL Server user defined function returns table -- cannot call it from select query

Tags: sql-server, user-defined-functions

I cannot get this type of select query (pseudo-code) to work. The UDF returns a table with 8 columns in a single row for a given 'UID_VEHICLE'.  It works perfectly when the 'UID_VEHICLE' is provided as a constant like 3308. But I need one row of these function-results for each vehicle for a given customer -- up to 100 rows to be returned.

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM
    [dbo].[fnGetNextDOT_InspectionData](UID_VEHICLE)
WHERE  
    UID_VEHICLE IN (SELECT UID_VEHICLE 
                    FROM tVEHICLES 
                    WHERE UID_CUSTOMER = 88);
```

Your comments and solutions are welcome...thanks...John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When passing row values from a query into a TVF, you need to use `CROSS APPLY` or `OUTER APPLY` (starting with SQL Server 2005):

```
SELECT   * -- or dot.*, or whatever is desired
FROM     tVEHICLES veh
CROSS APPLY [dbo].[fnGetNextDOT_InspectionData](veh.UID_VEHICLE) dot
WHERE    veh.UID_CUSTOMER = 88;
```

Comment: EXCELLENT!!! This is the answer, but with minor change..SELECT dot.*...  Thanks you very much -- you are very smart!!!

Comment: @JohnD Yer welcome, and I updated my answer with that. I didn't include it at first since I didn't know what columns you needed and figured you would change the `SELECT` as needed.

Comment: @srutzky...dear sir...Although I marked this as the answer, and I thank you for your answer, I find upon further examination of the result-set, I set the CROSS to OUTER and found that NOT all vehicles for customer=88 are being returned. Any ideas?

Comment: @JohnD Why would you change the `CROSS` to `OUTER`? Off hand it is impossible to say without seeing some data and the logic if the `InspectionData` TVF.

Comment: @srutzky...Thanks for the prompt reply.  Upon further research, I think it is due to the formulation of the TVF query statement that is faulty.  I found some blog-answers that a faulty where clause in LEFT OUTER JOIN can reduce the OUTER (intention) to an INNER when referencing a column belonging to the left-table.  I am letting you off the hook on this one for now, since I need to re-form the TVF query.  Do you want to see the code?

Comment: ...I changed to OUTER, because I need the data for each and every vehicle -- and the inspection data may be NULL in some cases. But that is OK, for the report will display default-values when the inspection fields are NULL.  thx...John